# i want to show hindi text in android but unable to parse

Tags: android, truetype, android-assets

I have added hindi .ttf file in assets and here is my code for the app

```
public class NanTV extends TextView{

private Context c;
public NanTV(Context c) {
      super(c);
    this.c = c;
    Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
            "vigyapti.ttf");
    setTypeface(tfs);

  }
public NanTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.c = context;
    Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
            "vigyapti.ttf");
    setTypeface(tfs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public NanTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.c = context;
    Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
            "vigyapti.ttf");
    setTypeface(tfs);

}
```

}
and when i try to show it in a textview in activity file like this

```
public class NanTV extends TextView{

private Context c;
public NanTV(Context c) {
    super(c);
    this.c = c;
    Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
            "vigyapti.ttf");
    setTypeface(tfs);

}
public NanTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.c = context;
    Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
            "vigyapti.ttf");
    setTypeface(tfs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

  public NanTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
    this.c = context;
    Typeface tfs = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
            "vigyapti.ttf");
      setTypeface(tfs);

  }
```

and i am getting the following errors in it

```
01-26 14:18:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-26 14:18:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(266): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{example.login/example.login.LoginActivity}:   

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class    
 com.nannu.NanTV
```

and here is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

  <com.nannu.NanTV
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 

    />
```

Kindly help me out in this as i need a quick sol
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

try using the `OpenTypeFont` file fonts